# My app stopped working out of nowhere, and I am clueless why

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, compiler-errors

I go these errors:

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> C:\Users\Uzivatel.gradle\caches\transforms-3\bd642b8b656b37eb31a733cc093832a8\transformed\core-1.6.0\res\values\values.xml:66:4:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

---

> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources
> C:\Users\Uzivatel.gradle\caches\transforms-3\bd642b8b656b37eb31a733cc093832a8\transformed\core-1.6.0\res\values\values.xml:66:4:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED

---

Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@9e5af3e.

yesterday it worked perfectly, and now I am lost cam you please help me?

I think it somehow depends on gradle, but I dont know how...

I tried to reload the old save that worked 100% because the app was okay even on mobile phone, but that suddenly didnt work too. I dont know how my app without any changes could stop working and I need your help. Thank yall very much <3

Comment: Please share the contents of your `res/values/values.xml` file. According to the logs there is a problem in line 66 of this file.

Comment: the line 66 looks like this: <item name="line3" type="id"/> I dont see anything wrong there...